# keywords of a website, loading infinitely, OOP

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I'm creating keywords from different websites, and save them in a bd.

In $webhtml, I have a websites downloaded with DOM. The problem is that when you start the extractor, is loaded infinitely. And never saves anything in the database.

The code that has the error is the follows:

```
if (empty($keywords)){
$ekeywords = new KeyPer;
$keywords = $ekeywords->Keys($webhtml);
}
```

I stored $keywords with a function:
saveweb($url, $description, $keywords);

And i use the next include:

```
include("Extkeys.php");
```

The code of "Extkeys":

```
<?php
class Extkeys {
function Keys($webhtml) { 
$webhtml = $this->clean($webhtml); 
$blacklist='de,la,los,las,el,ella,nosotros,yo,tu,el,te,mi,del,ellos'; 
$sticklist='test'; 
$minlength = 3; 
$count = 17; 

$webhtml = preg_replace('/[\.;:|\'|\"|\`|\,|\(|\)|\-]/', ' ', $webhtml); 
$webhtml = preg_replace('/¡/', '', $webhtml); 
$webhtml = preg_replace('/¿/', '', $webhtml);

$keysArray = explode(" ", $webhtml); 
$keysArray = array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', $keysArray)); 
$blackArray = explode(",", $blacklist); 

foreach($blackArray as $blackWord){ 
if(isset($keysArray[trim($blackWord)])) 
unset($keysArray[trim($blackWord)]); 
} 
arsort($keysArray); 
$i = 1; 
$keywords = ""; 
foreach($keysArray as $word => $instances){ 
if($i > $count) break; 
if(istrlen(trim($word)) >= $minlength && is_string($word)) { 
$keywords .= $word . ", "; 
$i++; 
} 
} 

$keywords = rtrim($keywords, ", "); 

return $keywords=$sticklist.''.$keywords; 
} 

function clean($webhtml) { 

$regex = '/(([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*)/iex'; 
$desc = preg_replace($regex, '', $webhtml); 
$webhtml = preg_replace( "''si", '', $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = preg_replace( '/]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/is', '\2 (\1)', $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = preg_replace( '//', '', $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = preg_replace( '/{.+?}/', '', $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = preg_replace( '/ /', ' ', $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = preg_replace( '/&/', ' ', $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = preg_replace( '/"/', ' ', $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = strip_tags( $webhtml ); 
$webhtml = htmlspecialchars($webhtml); 
$webhtml = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), " ", $webhtml); 

while (strchr($webhtml," ")) { 
$webhtml = str_replace(" ", " ",$webhtml); 
} 

for ($cnt = 1; 
$cnt < strlen($webhtml)-1; $cnt++) {
if (($webhtml{$cnt} == '.') || ($webhtml{$cnt} == ',')) { 
if ($webhtml{$cnt+1} != ' ') { 
$webhtml = substr_replace($webhtml, ' ', $cnt + 1, 0); 
} 
} 
} 
return $webhtml; 
} 
}
?>
```

How I can avoid the infinite load of code, and make it functional?

Best regards!

Comment: How do you know it's *infinite*?  Did you wait forever?

Comment: Well... no exactly, I waited for hours the execution of code

Comment: Instead of waiting hours you could have put simply some debug output in your loops and found the problem pretty quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are replacing space with space,

```
while (strchr($webhtml," ")) { 
    $webhtml = str_replace(" ", " ",$webhtml); 
}
```

it should be like

```
while (strchr($webhtml," ")) { 
    $webhtml = str_replace(" ", "",$webhtml); 
}
```

Comment: haha, I didn't realize, thanks for the help, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Dude I know what you are trying to do. You need **lynx** or **links** to dump some webpage to file (text file). You will skip with this all that stuff about removing tags etc, because both lynx and links are text based web browsers (usually started from command line in linux) and they are only showing text on page and not other stuff.

Also you keywords function is not good. You need **tf-idf**. [More about tf-idf here](http://goo.rs/tf-idf).

With tf-idf you can then extract real keywords from web page (this is how google keywords are made). Tf-idf is used to extract real text meaning, extract keywords that best describes page or document.

On that link I gave you you have formula for calculating tf-idf.

Comment: Thanks but I'm bad at math, haha. I will try with a little help implement the tf-idf in the code.

Thanks for reply!

Comment: No problem. If you need help write :)